# Storing multiple triples

Tags: java

I want to store triples X - Y - Z. There could be really big number of these triples and very common operation will be getting all triples by given X or by Y so this operation have to be as effective as possible. I would be grateful if someone could reccomend me the best way (container) to store these triples and search them as I mentioned before.

Comment: use `Map` and create your custom class with proper getter methods.

Comment: Where's the code you tried so far for it?

Comment: Look into Guava's Table datastructure.

Comment: You're saying X and Y can be keys? Are they of different types? You can define your own interface much like the `Map` and implement a bucket-style indexing as a regular `HashMap`, maybe even two-way indexing (by X and by Y).

Comment: What about BigInteger[][] or BigInteger[] and use % 3 to length to know the number of triples?